# Oracle SQL - Aggregate Elapsed Times within a particular range

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

Essentially I want to calculate, for a given item; which is opened, remains open, and then is closed; the amount of time which this item was in a particular state. The state information is contained in a table, while the open / close times are held in another. Visually represented below

```
      OPEN_TS [------------------------------------------] CLOSE_TS
   X1[----------] X2[-----] X1[----------] X2[----] X1[-----]

desired:
              --]             [----------]            [---
```

Working from the above diagram, I want to aggregate the amount of time this item spent in the state "X1" ONLY when the item was also OPEN. Basically find all the sections item A was OPEN and also in state X and aggregate all those time-stamps to get an total elapsed time (eg. 40 seconds spent open and in state X1)

Edit: attempt at a better diagram in excel. [image]

Edit 2: Tabular Representation of Data, Interested in aggregating amount of time spent in state 1 which falls between the open and close TS of the item with id 101
[image]

Comment: Hi can you provide some tabular data illustrating your diagram?

Comment: attempted to illustrate better, let me know if that makes sense

Comment: Maybe I am not all that smart, but I am reading your thing and I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Maybe if you have examples with "real life" data. Also, are the two diagrams supposed to represent the same situation?

Comment: Your diagram makes sense to me, but I don't know what to tell you to do with it without seeing what the table actually looks like and, preferably, seeing some sample data with expected results.  Also, if you've tried any queries, it's best to include them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I create the data that you showed in the tabular example:

```
with openLog as

    (
        select 101 ITEM_ID, to_date('06-SEP-17 10.30.48 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM') OPEN_TS,
               to_date('06-SEP-17 10.44.48 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM') CLOSE_TS
        from dual
        union all
        select 102 ITEM_ID, to_date('06-SEP-17 10.30.48 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM') OPEN_TS,
               to_date('06-SEP-17 10.44.48 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM') CLOSE_TS
        from dual
    ),
    stateLog as
    (
        select 101 ITEM_ID, to_date('06-SEP-17 10.29.48 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM') STATE_START_TS,
               1 STATE, 2 NEXT_STATE
        from dual
        union all
        select 101 ITEM_ID, to_date('06-SEP-17 10.31.48 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM') STATE_START_TS,
               2 STATE, 1 NEXT_STATE
        from dual
        union all
        select 101 ITEM_ID, to_date('06-SEP-17 10.32.48 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM') STATE_START_TS,
               1 STATE, 2 NEXT_STATE
        from dual
        union all
        select 101 ITEM_ID, to_date('06-SEP-17 10.34.48 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM') STATE_START_TS,
               2 STATE, 1 NEXT_STATE
        from dual
        union all
        select 101 ITEM_ID, to_date('06-SEP-17 10.42.48 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM') STATE_START_TS,
               1 STATE, 3 NEXT_STATE
        from dual
        union all
        select 101 ITEM_ID, to_date('06-SEP-17 10.45.48 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM') STATE_START_TS,
               3 STATE, null NEXT_STATE
        from dual
    )
```

Here is the full query which I will break down part by part:

```
select ITEM_ID, STATE, sum(SecondsDifference) SecondsDifference
from(
select ITEM_ID, STATE, (lead(state_start_ts,1) over(partition by ITEM_ID order by state_start_ts) - state_start_ts) * 24 * 60 * 60 SecondsDifference
from(
select  openLog.ITEM_ID,
        case when openLog.OPEN_TS > STATE_START_TS and openLog.OPEN_TS < lead(STATE_START_TS,1) over(partition by openLog.ITEM_ID order by state_start_ts)
        then openLog.OPEN_TS 
        when openLog.CLOSE_TS < STATE_START_TS then openLog.CLOSE_TS
        else STATE_START_TS end STATE_START_TS,
        stateLog.STATE
from openLog
join stateLog on openLog.ITEM_ID = stateLog.ITEM_ID))
group by  ITEM_ID, STATE
;
```

The innermost query takes the OPEN_TS and compares it to the STATE_START_TS to find out when to actually start counting seconds and also ends at the CLOSE_TS if the next time stamp is after the close:

```
select  openLog.ITEM_ID,
        case when openLog.OPEN_TS > STATE_START_TS and openLog.OPEN_TS < lead(STATE_START_TS,1) over(partition by openLog.ITEM_ID order by state_start_ts)
        then openLog.OPEN_TS 
        when openLog.CLOSE_TS < STATE_START_TS then openLog.CLOSE_TS
        else STATE_START_TS end STATE_START_TS,
        stateLog.STATE
from openLog
join stateLog on openLog.ITEM_ID = stateLog.ITEM_ID
```

I then wrapped that query to calculate the difference between the current STATE_START_TS and the leading STATE_START_TS (using the lead window function)

```
select ITEM_ID, STATE, (lead(state_start_ts,1) over(partition by ITEM_ID order by state_start_ts) - state_start_ts) * 24 * 60 * 60 SecondsDifference
from(
select  openLog.ITEM_ID,
        case when openLog.OPEN_TS > STATE_START_TS and openLog.OPEN_TS < lead(STATE_START_TS,1) over(partition by openLog.ITEM_ID order by state_start_ts)
        then openLog.OPEN_TS 
        when openLog.CLOSE_TS < STATE_START_TS then openLog.CLOSE_TS
        else STATE_START_TS end STATE_START_TS,
        stateLog.STATE
from openLog
join stateLog on openLog.ITEM_ID = stateLog.ITEM_ID)
```

Then finally, group by the item ID and state and sum up the seconds:

```
select ITEM_ID, STATE, sum(SecondsDifference) SecondsDifference
from(
select ITEM_ID, STATE, (lead(state_start_ts,1) over(partition by ITEM_ID order by state_start_ts) - state_start_ts) * 24 * 60 * 60 SecondsDifference
from(
select  openLog.ITEM_ID,
        case when openLog.OPEN_TS > STATE_START_TS and openLog.OPEN_TS < lead(STATE_START_TS,1) over(partition by openLog.ITEM_ID order by state_start_ts)
        then openLog.OPEN_TS 
        when openLog.CLOSE_TS < STATE_START_TS then openLog.CLOSE_TS
        else STATE_START_TS end STATE_START_TS,
        stateLog.STATE
from openLog
join stateLog on openLog.ITEM_ID = stateLog.ITEM_ID))
group by  ITEM_ID, STATE
```

Comment: I forgot about the CLOSE_TS. Give me a sec and I will update it.

Comment: Updated. Please try the new version

Comment: I was going to add a comment before I saw you already took care of it, you're too good. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

OK with no data sample(s) provided I will try to be creative:

```
select sum(
  case when t2.close <= t1.close then t2.close else t1.close
 -
  case when t2.open >= t1.open then t2.open else t1.open end 
  )
from t1 cross join t2
where t2.state = 'X1';
```

Let's use the above as a baseline to discuss!

Ted.

Comment: Added some tabular representation of the data to better illustrate the problem. Appreciate you taking a shot in the dark with my shoddy explanation

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks for the data, here is another attempt

```
select sum(
  case when t2.close_ts <= t1.state_end_ts then t2.close else t1.state_end_ts 
 -
  case when t2.open_ts >= t1.state_start_ts then t2.open_ts else t1.state_start_ts  end 
  )
from t1
join t2 on t1.item_id = t2.item_id
where t1.state = 'X1';
```

Getting closer???